# jquery mobile all the data attribute references does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

In my header i included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
```

and whenever I use for example `data-role="page"` the expected effect does not acquire.

why would that happen?

edit: https://jsfiddle.net/f0eurafv/1/
 notice the text input in the login form

Comment: Please provide a plnkr or fiddle link

Comment: Are you sure that these files are actually in your js folder ?

Comment: it works as it should in the https://jsfiddle.net/60swbwre/ but not on my device

Comment: and yes i am suer they are in the js folder

Comment: Watch for errors in the browser console. Please post also your full HTML.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f0eurafv/1/ my full html,css and js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to your fiddle-link (https://jsfiddle.net/f0eurafv/1/):

The problem is that you have bound a click-function to your `<h2>`-tags in which you manually fadeIn/fadeOut your different pages. In this case jQuery-mobile will not do the work for you (switching to the other page) and as a side effect it will not render the elements in the page correctly (the inputs for example).

You can try to call the changePage()-function of jQuery-mobile in your click-function instead and find a way to change the transition-effect (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/transitions/):

```
$('#loginA').click(function(){
    $.mobile.changePage('#loginform');
});
```

Or you put `<a>`-tags with an `href`-attribute to the page-ID which should be opened around your links:

```
<div id="sliderA" data-role="content"><h2 id="loginA"><a href="#loginform">Login</a></h2></div>
```